# How do I implement/enable blanket nohup in the shell?

Tags: bash, nohup

Something like a shell option or "mode" that protects all GUI processes run within that session from being killed when I kill the shell. It would be the equivalent of using nohup for each of the processes.

Comment: To make this extra clear. I want to be able to kill the *shell* (including its virtual terminal, or tmux, or screen) without this killing its processes. So no, by *shell* I did not just mean virtual terminal.

Comment: Shell has no way of knowing whether or not if process is GUI program or not, so I doubt there's a way to "automate" that. Personally, if I know it's a GUI app, I run it with `nohup gui_app > /dev/null 2>&1  &`  right away.

Comment: Yes, but the shell has no way of knowing whether the process is GUI or not either.

Comment: And your point is ?

Comment: My nohup mode doesn't care if things break with some applications. It was an argument against "shifting the... question".

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to run all commands inside of a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or GNU `screen`. Then if you detach from the `tumx` or `screen` session or are disconnected from an `ssh` session, the commands you are running will continue and not get a `SIGHUP`. You can reattach and essentially pick up where you left off.

This method is a great way to do any remote administration where you do not want to get disconnected while doing something important or long running.

Comment: ... unless systemd gets frisky and for some reason nukes some processes

Comment: also no protection against lasers either.